A basic question about using dielectric material in PCB boards in relation to electric field
I was wondering what the PCB's dielectric material(such as FR-4) do to the electric field.
If I'm not wrong, the dielectric material influences how the electric field lines are distributed. And it seems the dielectric material(such as FR-4) makes electric filed lines closer comparing air and therefore dielectric can influence the capacitance and characteristic impedance between the traces or capacitance between a trace and ground plane.
Does it mean all the goal is to concentrate electric flux? But does it mean it is beneficial when the circuit acts like a distributed circuit(transmission line behaviour) or is there any benefit if the circuit has no fast rising edge or all behaves like in lumped circuit model?

There is no explicit goal to concentrate electric flux. FR-4 has useful mechanical characteristics and one of the downsides is that electric flux is raised by about 4.4. This can be a disadvantage especially when the frequency rises above 1 GHz. A PCB t-line isn't a distributed/lumped model.

does the concentration of electric filed lines(hence the dielectric material) affect the range and amount of cross talk?

The circuit board is the only "component" that touches every node. Between every node it introduces capacitance (more than air) and between node connections it introduces inductance (same as air would). So, you have to respect it and design it to suit the circuit needs.

@GNZ, If we compare the precise case of capacitive coupling between two tracks on a PCB composed of different substrates, then yes, there will be less crosstalk with a low-Dk material.

@GNZ Watch this video. Near the very end an expert on PCB layout also makes a comment. But the video is about how reality works. It is a simple case, but applies when thinking about more complex situations like board design.

Forget about the field lines, they are just a visualizaton of the field; at least personally, I find them when changing through media very confusing, compared to the "simple" idea of the vector field having a direction and magnitude at any point.

Does it mean all the goal is to concentrate electric flux?

No.

But does it mean it is beneficial when the circuit acts like a distributed circuit(transmission line behaviour) or is there any benefit if the circuit has no fast rising edge or all behaves like in lumped circuit model?

Whether a higher or lower \$\varepsilon_r\$ is of advantage or disadvantage depends on what you want to do, and at which frequency. There's simply no general statement to be made here, and things will fully depend on the device you're building. That's why board houses offer different substrates and different board layer stackups.

But doesn't the concentration of electric filed lines(hence the dielectric material) affect the range and amount of cross talk?

@GNZ among many other things. Whether that is something you need or don't want depends on your application. As said already! You of course design your product to have traces layed out such that   with exactly the board material and thickness, you get the properties you want.

@GNZ it's not like someone goes and lays a board out for "any" substrate. You do it for a specific board material and geometry.
